# ReactJs.NET - ScriptBundling with Server-side component rendering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I have just followed the tutorial [here](http://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html), which was great but the last 2 sections discuss Bundling & Minification, and Server-side rendering, respectively. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to describe how to make these two play nicely, e.g pass a script bundle to the server-side rendering function.

**This is what I have so far:**

In `BundleConfig.RegisterBundles`  I have the following:

```
bundles.Add(New BabelBundle("~/bundles/main").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/showdown.js", 
                        "~/Scripts/Tutorial.jsx"))

BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = True
```

I can render that bundle nice and easily in the view, so if that bundle ends up with a lot of files I only have to update the list in `BundleConfig`.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/main")
```

But in `ReactConfig.Configure` I can't seem to use the bundle, I have to repeat the list of scripts I passed to `BundleConfig`:

```
//This doesn't work and throws the following error:
//Could not find a part of the path '\\pathToMyProject\bundles\main'
ReactSiteConfiguration.Configuration
.AddScript("~/bundles/main")

//This does, but it's basically a repeat of BundleConfig
ReactSiteConfiguration.Configuration
.AddScript("~/Scripts/showdown.js")
.AddScript("~/Scripts/Tutorial.jsx")
```

Is there a nice easy way to get it to use the same bundle that it is about to render for the view that is loading?

Comment: Whats the error you get in the web browser console? What you you observe when you say `But in ReactConfig.Configure I can't seem to use the bundle`? Could it be the order of the scripts or mangled variable names after minification in your bundle?

Comment: I don't get an error in the browser, it's fine bundling for the view but I can't pass `~/bundles/main` to `ReactConfig` as it looks for a file in that location instead of generated a minified bundle from the `BundleConfig`

Comment: The error I get from the server when using `.AddScript("~/bundles/main")` is `Could not find a part of the path '\\pathToMyProject\bundles\main'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may already have a solution by now, FWIW, here is what you can try, the first 2 steps you may have already carried out, 3rd one is what you are after...

1. Comment out `[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(YourApp), "Configure")]` at the top of ReactConfig.cs
2. In your `Application_Start()`, after `RegisterBundles()` you can now insert the call to `ReactConfig.Configure();` This makes sure your bundles are actually registered before trying to do anything with them.
3. Finally in ReactConfig.cs, Add this line

   ```
   var myBabelBundlePath = BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/myBabelBundleName"); 
   ReactSiteConfiguration.Configuration.AddScript(myBabelBundlePath);
   ```

Comment: Nice, i think i sacked the whole thing off for webpacked script bundles in the end, but that does look like it would have solved that problem.

Comment: Hi CodeReaper, I`m getting issue with reference one component to my app.jsx file. How to use my component in app.jsx ? eg. I have checkbox.jsx component and how to import in app.jsx file. I`m using 
 bundles.Add(new BabelBundle("~/bundles/main").Include(
                     "~/Scripts/react/Checkbox.jsx", "~/Scripts/react/App.jsx"));